# awk manipulation of fasta file

Tags: awk

I have a file like this

```
>chr1
ACGTGGC
TGCCGTT
ATCCTTG
>chr2
ACTTTTA
CTCATAA
```

I want to convert the seq into 1 string. This should be the output:

```
>chr1
ACGTGGCTGCCGTTATCCTTG
>chr2
ACTTTTACTCATAA
```

How can i do it using awk. I know how to do it in Perl.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This should work as expected :

```
awk '/>chr/{if (x)print x;print;x="";next}{x=(!x)?$0:x$0;}END{print x;}' file

>chr1
ACGTGGCTGCCGTTATCCTTG
>chr2
ACTTTTACTCATAA
```

Comment: HI, Can you explain the code??

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using a very specific file format, I made the assumption that the first record is always in the form of `><string>`:

```
< inputfile awk 'NR==1 {print;next} !/>/ {x=x$0;next} />/ {print x"\n"$0;x="";next} END {print x}' > outputfile
```

Expanded:

```
NR==1 {
    print;
    next
}
!/>/ {
    x=x$0;
    next
}
/>/ {
    print x"\n"$0;
    x="";
    next
}
END {
    print x
}
```

- The first block is executed only if the currently processed record number is 1: it prints the currently processed record and skips to the next record;
- The second block is executed only if the `>` regular expression doesn't match the currently processed record: it concatenates the content of the currently processed record to the variable `x` and skips to the next record;
- The third block is executed only if the `>` regular expression matches the currently processed record: it prints the content of the `x` variable immediately followed by a newline character immediately followed by the content of the currently processed record and skips to the next record;
- The fourth block is executed only if there are no more records to process: it prints the content of the `x` variable;

I benchmarked all of the answers to this question checking the `md5sum` of the output files on a SSD right after the system startup and right after having issued a `sudo fstrim -v /` command, using the following `bash` script, where `outputfile` is a ~226MB file created by repeating the file at [this link](http://www.cbs.dtu.dk/services/NetGene2/fasta.php) 100000 times:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

for ((i=0; i<3; i++)); do /usr/bin/time -f "kos\t\treal %e" awk 'NR==1 {print;next} !/>/ {x=x$0;next} />/ {print x"\n"$0;x="";next} END{print x}' outputfile > outputfile1; done
for ((i=0; i<3; i++)); do /usr/bin/time -f "Peter.O\t\treal %e" awk 'BEGIN{ RS=">[^\n]+\n"; }NR>1{ printf( "%s", rt gensub("\n","","g") "\n" ); }{ rt=RT; }' outputfile > outputfile2; done
for ((i=0; i<3; i++)); do /usr/bin/time -f "user2196728\treal %e" awk '/>/{if (x)print x;print;x="";next}{x=(!x)?$0:x$0;}END{print x;}' outputfile > outputfile3; done
md5sum outputfile1 outputfile2 outputfile3
```

These are the resuls:

```bsh
~$ sudo fstrim -v /
[sudo] password for user: 
/: 68,8 GiB (73839202304 bytes) trimmed
~$ cd tmp
~/tmp$ bash exe
kos         real 2.55
kos         real 2.57
kos         real 2.55
Peter.O     real 2.93
Peter.O     real 2.92
Peter.O     real 2.92
user2196728 real 2.51
user2196728 real 2.51
user2196728 real 2.68
0618a8077b43eb44eb263d7d6f84777f  outputfile1
0618a8077b43eb44eb263d7d6f84777f  outputfile2
0618a8077b43eb44eb263d7d6f84777f  outputfile3
```

Comment: HI, Can you explain the code?

Comment: @user3138373 Done, check the updated answer

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'BEGIN{ RS=">[^\n]+\n"; } 
     NR>1{ printf( "%s", rt gensub("\n","","g") "\n" ); }
     { rt=RT; }' myfile
```

Output:

```
>chr1
ACGTGGCTGCCGTTATCCTTG
>chr2
ACTTTTACTCATAA
```

---

For general reference: Using input data from [FASTA format example](http://www.cbs.dtu.dk/services/NetGene2/fasta.php), and repeating it to make an *81.1 MB* test file, I got the following `time` results:

```
Peter.O      real  0m1.653s   user  0m1.396s   sys  0m0.256s
user2196728  real  0m6.587s   user  0m5.972s   sys  0m0.252s
kos          real  0m12.866s  user  0m12.589s  sys  0m0.268s
```

The `md5sum` of all tested methods were the same.
`user2196728`'s version needed to have `>chr` changed to just `>` to work more generally.

Comment: How are you testing this? I'm on a SSD, so that might make the differences stick out less because of the high I/O, however I'm getting very different results: using a ~226MB file created by repeating the data in your link 100000 times my script runs in `0m5.398s`, your script runs in `0m4.881s` and user2196728's script runs in `0m4.525s` (fastest). Doubling the sample input (`cat inputfile inputfile > inputfile2`) i get `0m10.723s` `0m9.469s` `0m8.134s`. So Indeed my script is the slowest, however user2196728's script always run the fastest for me.

Comment: My test was reading `myfile` from a SATA disk-drive – so it may well be that the  I/O load of handling multi-line *Records* vs. individual LF-delimited *Lines* is the significant factor. I don't have an SSD drive to test with, but I tried `vfile="$(<myfile)"; printf '%s\n' "$vfile" |  awk` – the 3 results were very similar timewise (in the same order as you got) – surprisingly the `awk` step  ran significantly slower in all cases! – I suppose tthat means disk-caching works!

Comment: I guess that's the reason. Anyway I was able to enhance my script, and I ran a series of benchmark again; check my answer for the script I used to perform the benchmark and for the results. If you feel like so you could post your results using the same script, it would be interesting to see how results compare on a SSD and on a HDD (and moreover I believe that results on a HDD are way more reliable source to spot the fastest script)